# Describe the Transpose of $A= \left[\matrix{0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 &1 &1} \right]$

Tags: matrices, matlab

$$A= \left[\matrix{0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
} \right]$$

```
Q: What does the spy(A') output look like? Describe?
```

I have been able to find `A'` (A Trnapose) in `Matlab`, and it looks identical to the original `A` matrix. However, I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the original matrix back!

Comment: maybe because your matrix is self-adjoint

Comment: side note: `A'` operation is not transpose, but conjugate transpose, a.k.a Hermitian adjoint.

Comment: well if you have an $nxn$ matrix you will have the original matrix back. If $A$ is a  $3x3$ matrix, then $A^T$ will be a $3x3$ matrix as well.

Comment: Following up on @Memming's comment, `.'` denotes the "normal" transpose.  IIRC.

Comment: The question in the title is not the same as the question in the body.  Which of the two is your *real* question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transpose just takes each ith column of the original matrix and assigns it to the ith row of the transposed.

What does this do to your particular matrix?